# Text + Image + Text GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

Estoy intentando meter una `img` que recibo en formato `Blob` dentro de una `cell` de la `Gridview`, la convierto a url mediante el siguiente metodo:

```
  cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = conn1;
    cmd1.CommandText = "select * from simbolos_ll";
    string url = null;
    try
    {
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr["idsimb"].ToString().Equals(id))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = conn1;
                cmd2.CommandText = "select simbolo from simbolos_ll where idsimb=" + id;
                OracleDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();
                OracleLob blob = null;
                blob = dr2.GetOracleLob(0);
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])blob.Value;
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                url = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

            }

        }
```

una vez tengo la url de la `img` , deseo meterla entre un texto de una `cell` de una `Gridview`.

Mi problema esta en que no se la manera de hacer que aparezca `Text1` + `Img` + `text2` dentro de la misma celda de la Grid View.
Alguna idea o tutotial donde pueda mirar como hacerlo?

Anotaciones :

-La `GridView`se rellena con una consulta diferente a la que consigo la `Img`.

-La `Img` depende de un dato que se haya marcado dentro de un `string` de una de las celdas de la `Gridview`.

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido la posibilidad de: Teniendo el `HTMLEncode = false` , añadir directamente mediante una etiqueta guardada en un `string` al texto de la celda, parecido a lo siguiente : `GridView.Columns[i].Cells[10].text += "<img src= 'urldelaimagen'>"`. Funcionaria?